How long does it take to use 3 Efreet Wishes?
I have a problem with how unspecific the wording "1/day—grant up to 3 wishes" is. What does this mean from a mechanics standpoint?

Is granting a Wish mechanically identical to casting a Wish but without a cost? Casting Time is my main concern here.
Is it 1 "cast" of Wish with results equating that of 3 "casts" of Wish or is it 3 separate "casts" of Wish, just worded terribly?
If it is a single "cast" of Wish, do I have to decide all 3 Wishes at the same time?

Wording is my main problem here, since for example the Shaitan noble (which does pretty much the same thing as Efreeti) has "ability to grant up to three wishes per day" which sounds more like separate "castings" of Wish.

Similar question for D&D 3.5. For your question's sake, I hope Pathfinder is more forthcoming than its antecedent.

The Effeeti grants the ability to cast wish spells
If you look at the Spell Like Abilities section of the Efreeti, it looks like this:

Spell-Like Abilities (CL 11th)
Constant—detect magic
At Will—plane shift (willing targets to elemental planes, Astral Plane, or Material Plane only), produce flame, pyrotechnics (DC 14), scorching ray
3/day—invisibility, quickened scorching ray, wall of fire (DC 16)
1/day—grant up to 3 wishes (to nongenies only), gaseous form, permanent image (DC 18)

All1 the abilities are spell effects, and the wishes are also italicized, as it standard notation for indicating spells. That is a pretty clear clue that these are wish spells. The reason this is written so strangely is because the Efreeti cannot itself cast wish spells, it only can grant up to three wishes to nongenies who ask for them. The grantee then can formulate their wishes and cast the spells.2 Granting the wishes is a standard action according to the rules for spell-like abilities:

Using all other [i.e. not Constant] spell-like abilities is a standard action unless noted otherwise, and doing so provokes attacks of opportunity.

The grantee then speaking all three wishes would take at least another 3 standard actions, because the casting time of wish is also a standard action. How long the grantee can wait between wishes is not further specified, and up to the DM.

1 Invisibility, for some weird reason is not italicized on AoN. Apparently this is a formatting error by AoN, and it is in italics in the print version; thanks to @williwontu.
2 For example, there is a whole adventure path, Legacy of Fire, that revolves around an Effreti's plan to overcome the inability of Efreet to formulate wishes themselves. From the introduction of the last installment, "The Final Wish" (p. 7)

So the powerful efreeti turned his attention back to his
original plan—to use his own wishes, siphoned through
mortal lips, to absorb and infuse himself with the essence
of a great monster of yore

and on p. 56

Such tales exaggerate much, but at their root lies a single
undeniable truth: some genies can grant wishes. Blessed with the might to reorder reality, yet cursed never to take advantage of their own powers, genies both take pride in their incredible ability and resent that their gift can only serve the wills of lesser creatures.

and p. 57

Regardless of how they come by their powers, though, genies
possess one law that rules over their ability: no genie may
grant wishes to another genie, especially themselves.


wish makers who entreat genies to perform tasks that
could naturally occur are more likely to find their wishes
granted as they desire, while those who presume to make
wild demands of reality often find themselves thwarted by
offended genie wishcrafters

That is, the genie grants the power to the nongenie to make wishes, the nongenie then casts those wishes (note the wish in "wish makers" is in italics). And all the grantee has to do is to speak their wish to cast it. As per the spell's description:

Wish is the mightiest spell a Wizard or Sorcerer can cast. By simply speaking aloud, you can alter reality to better suit you.

And it then is the genies inherent ability to fullfill the wish that has been cast, or thwart it if it is overreaching. (At traditionally done for wishes by the DM, who plays the genie).
I think this is not fully mechanically sound, because what happens if the genie dies after it granted the power to make those wishes? But that probably needs to be resolved by the DM, and also is not the focus of the question here, the question is about the action economy of the wish-granting spell like ability. And that just is a standard action, without the genie casting any whishes at that time.

Invisibility is italicized in the book for their SLA's so it's just an editing error on AoN's part.

To be honest that doesn't explain any of my questions. Is it 3 wishes in a single standard action? I actually consider using it in combat as action economy booster combined with early access to up-to-8th-level-spells but without knowing how long it takes I can't do anything.

It is NO wishes in a single action, it is granting the power to speak 3 wishes. Then the grantee needs to use the normal actions to cast wishes.

This relies exclusively on one text. Pathfinder must've used the occasional efreet in its myriad of adventure paths. Do any of them back up this reading? (I think you're correct, by the way, but this is not how any other media typically depict genies granting wishes, so fortifying your answer with other sources would make it more persuasive.)

@HeyICanChan I managed to dig something up. It is not totally watertight, but it makes it clear that the other creatures must mouth the wishes, not the efreeti, and they cannot just cast them themselves

And, from action economy perspective, who is specifically "casting" the Wishes? Efreeti or his Master? Because shouting quick orders doesn't take action so I can scream "give me this buff" and let the Efreeti use his action economy to make it happen, assuming Efreeti is the one doing the "casting".

@NecXelos The creature that the efreeti granted the wishes to is casting the wishes. Just as if they were casting normal wishes. There is nothing special about it, I'm not quite sure how else I can say it. Efreeti, 1 action "Here Omar, you have 3 wishes free". Omar, 1st action "I wish I a new camel" (Poof, new camel), Omar, 2nd action "I wish my crippled foot was good again." (Poof, healed). Omar, 3rd action "I wish I was a demigod" (Poof, Omar is now part of Yggfried the Many-faced, a mad  demigod composed of 1000s of sinners. Because, wish too big, so take that.)

I actually was understanding it the other way around. Master says "I want a Pony" and then Efreeti is casting a Wish to create the pony. Is there any source backing up the "Efreeti is infusing you with ability to cast Wish 3 times" interpretation?

@NecXelos The entire answer is about that, with all the references. Eg the Effreeti having to have siphoned their wishes through mortal lips. The efreeti granting 3 wishes as a single action because it is a spell like ability to do so. Wish makers entreating the efreeti for tasks etc. what makes you think it is the other way round? Is there anything suggesting that? Where does it say the efreeti can cast wishes?

Simple: ability is property of Efreeti, not the master who summoned it. There is literally nothing in the entire game making precedent for "I have the ability, but someone else actually has to use it, including all the steps". The way I see it caster just states what he wants, Efreeti is the one doing the work, he just can't do it without mortal ordering him to do so. There is nothing in the source material that would suggest otherwise. My question was only about how long it takes Efreeti to do those wishes, because as stated before, talking is free action so it's free for the master.

@NecXelos The entire adventure path is based on the premise that genie just cannot cast wishes themselves or even grant it to other genies, and one genie wants to break that with a thousand  wishes it were otherwise. But it seems your mind on this is set. My recommendation, if you believe that is the right answer, is to self-answer with your take on it. That will allow you both to make the full reasoning in the space you’d want, and also keep that perspective where comments might just go away.

You see, what I'm looking for is either RAW or closest possible interpretation to the spirit of RAW. Fluff tends to derail RAW a lot so infering anything from it results in plethora of nonsenses. You also seem to not see the difference between casting Wish and being able to decide what You wish for. If they can cast Wish that does nothing and require mortal to speak what Wish is supposed to do your story example still checks out. But mechanically those are separate situations.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I feel honored that you linked to my 5E Map Making question here, but that was probably a mistake.

@TreeSpawned Yes, not sure how that happend, I fixed it, thank you!
